# How to change the state object when one of the fields is an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a state tree of this form:

```
    const initialState = {
    total: 0,
    discount: 0,
    typeDiscount: 0,
    products: data
};
```

In which products field is an array and the array is like this:

```
[{
   "id":9090,
   "name":"Item1",
   "price":200,
   "discount":10,
   "type":"fiction",
   "quantity": 1,
   "img_url":"https://store.lexisnexis.com.au/__data/media/catalog/thumb//placeholder.jpg"
},
{
   "id":9091,
   "name":"Item2",
   "price":250,
   "discount":15,
   "type":"literature",
   "quantity": 1,
   "img_url":"https://store.lexisnexis.com.au/__data/media/catalog/thumb//placeholder.jpg"
}]
```

Now I'm trying to change the quantity in that array, I'm new to Redux so please guide me on how to do this?

And here is my reducer:

```
case types.ADD_ITEM_CART:
        let product_add = state.products
        for (let i = 0; i < product_add.length; i++) {
            if (product_add[i].id === action.id) {
                product_add[i].quantity = product_add[i].quantity + 1
                break
            }
        }
        return dotProp.set(state, `products`, product_add);
```

Comment: Which object's quantity do you want to change?

Comment: In the product field of initialState object I want to change quantity.

Comment: Don't mutate your state like this, there are better ways. So, you have an `id` coming from your action payload, right? Then you want to increment the quantity by one?

Comment: Yes, right. How do I do that? I'm new to this and I always get confused in this.

Comment: you need to overwrite the products in the state with the new products that is product_add so return {...state, product: product_add} and if you want to follow the redux way, you have to deep copy from the state (let product_add = {...state.products } for you case) instead of copying the reference so the original data is immutable , remember the state is immutable so copy and overwrite only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the spread operator `...` and `array.map()` you can create a new products array where all the products that do not match the id will keep the same object reference while you create a new product object for you product of interest:

```
case types.ADD_ITEM_CART:
    const updatedProducts = state.products.map(product => {
       if (product.id === action.id) {
            const newQuantity = product.quantity + 1;
            return { ...product, quantity: newQuantity };
        }

        return product;
    })

    return { ...state, products: updatedProducts };
}
```

**Edit:** Remove can be easily implemented with the `array.filter()` method, which will create a new array only containing the items that matches your predicate function; in this case all the products that does not match the id of the product you want to remove:

```
 case types.REMOVE_ITEM_CART:
    const updatedProducts = state.products.filter(product => product.id !== action.id)

    return { ...state, products: updatedProducts };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and iterate over the items and update the item that matches the `id` from the payload.

Something like that:

```js
const state = [{
    "id": 9090,
    "name": "Item1",
    "price": 200,
    "discount": 10,
    "type": "fiction",
    "quantity": 1,
    "img_url": "https://store.lexisnexis.com.au/__data/media/catalog/thumb//placeholder.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 9091,
    "name": "Item2",
    "price": 250,
    "discount": 15,
    "type": "literature",
    "quantity": 1,
    "img_url": "https://store.lexisnexis.com.au/__data/media/catalog/thumb//placeholder.jpg"
  }
];

const payload = {
  id: 9091
};

const nextState = state.map(product => {
  if (product.id !== payload.id) {
    // not our product, return as is
    return product;
  }
  return {
    ...product,
    quantity: product.quantity + 1
  }
});

console.log(nextState);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

For removal of items you can just use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const state = [{
    "id": 9090,
    "name": "Item1",
    "price": 200,
    "discount": 10,
    "type": "fiction",
    "quantity": 1,
    "img_url": "https://store.lexisnexis.com.au/__data/media/catalog/thumb//placeholder.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 9091,
    "name": "Item2",
    "price": 250,
    "discount": 15,
    "type": "literature",
    "quantity": 1,
    "img_url": "https://store.lexisnexis.com.au/__data/media/catalog/thumb//placeholder.jpg"
  }
];

const payload = {
  id: 9091
};

const nextState = state.filter(product => product.id !== payload.id);

console.log(nextState);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not mutate your state like that for Redux or React itself. Copying objects do not create different objects. If you change a property for the new one, you mutate the original one also.

Generally, we use `Object.assign` or spread syntax combining with methods like `.map`, `.filter`. `Object.assign` or spread syntax does not create totally different objects, too. They create shallow copies, this means one level copy. If you change a nested property for the new object then again you mutate the original one. So, combine all these tools.

```
case types.ADD_ITEM_CART: {
    // We are mapping our related array.
    const newProducts = state.products.map( el => {
      // If id does not match, return the element without doing nothing.
      if ( el.id !== action.id ) { return el };
      // id match, increment the quantity.
      return { ...el, quantity: el.quantity + 1 };
    })
    // Lastly, return our state again without mutating it.
    return { ...state, products: newProducts };
}
```

If we want to remove an item from an array we generally use `.filter` method for this.

```
const newProducts = state.products.filter( el => el.id !== action.id );
return { ...state, products: newProducts };
```